# cmake4eclipse and -D options

Tags: eclipse, cmake, eclipse-plugin

I have a CMake project (native Linux) which I imported into Eclipse using cmake4eclipse.

The build process includes downloading some sample data which is rarely needed in production use. Currently this step fails (causing the whole build to fail), which is why I would like to skip it in the build.

The build chain supports skipping tis step. Running CMake from the command line, I would simply do `-DSAMPLE_DATA=n`.

With cmake4eclipse, where would I specify this option? I have tried adding it in Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > CMake, but it takes no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > CMake, on the Symbols tab, add a new variable. For `-DSAMPLE_DATA=n`, add `SAMPLE_DATA`, type `STRING`, value `n`.

**After that, on the General tab, check “Force cmake to run with each build” and build once.** For subsequent builds you can clear the check mark again—you just need to run this once so Eclipse/CMake will pick up the new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

add it on the CMake|Symols tab in the project proerties.

Comment: I did that, adding SAMPLE_DATA, type BOOL, value FALSE (the CMake script treats it as boolean), to no avail. I also tried setting the value to `n`, then changing the type to STRING, still no joy. What am I doing wrong here?